# order database tables by creation time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-metadata

hi i want to list all my tables from a database and order them by time, how can i do that so far i can list all my tables from the database but i can't order them by time;

```
$dbname = "album";

if (!mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")) {
echo "Could not connect to mysql";
exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo "MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$sorts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "Table: {$row[0]}"."<br>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: What does order by time mean?

Comment: i want to order tables by the time they were created

Comment: You need to add a column in your table for the date created. Then you can use `NOW()` when inserting to get the date created.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you:

```
$sql = "
SELECT create_time, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '$dbname'
ORDER BY create_time
";
```

Also change while loop's inner part as below:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row['table_name']} - {$row['create_time']} <br/>";
}
```

Comment: You should probably select the table name as well.

Comment: the code above display time only not the names of the tables.

Comment: i have edited again, check that too, didn't see that you've used `mysql_fetch_row`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) tables

```
select * from information_schema.columns
order by create_time, column_name, table_name;
```

Or if you want a more narrow resultset:

```
select column_name, table_name, data_type, character_maximum_length,
is_nullable, column_default, create_time
from information_schema.columns
order by create_time, column_name, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be the solution

```
select * from information_schema.columns
order by create_time, column, table;
```